# Show that the differential equation of a family is linear.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We know from

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXJuk.jpg

that the general solution of a first order linear equation is a family of curves of the form

y = cf(x) + g(x).

Show, conversely, that the differential equation of any such family is linear.

I did not under stand what the question meant by the differential equation of the family. Is it merely referring to the above equation differentiated?

Comment: Just differentiate the formula, apply the known theorems on the derivatives of composite function, of integral, etc., and make appropriate substitutions to obtain an ODE.